# Different generic types in object

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

How can I get different types for the `Config` `K` type by having it nested inside a type like `MyType` as seen below?

```
type Config<K> = {
  value: K;
  onUpdate: (value: K) => void;
}

type MyType<F extends string> = {
  [K in F]: <V>() => Config<V>;
}

// I want this to be possible
const hello: MyType<'setup1'|'setup2'> = {
  setup1: () => ({
    value: { hello: 'world' },
    onUpdate: record => console.log(record.hello),
  }),
  setup2: () => ({
    value: { goodbye: 'world' },
    onUpdate: record => console.log(record.goodbye),
  }),
};
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strictPropertyInitialization=false#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwGYEsDmAeA0gPigXigG8AoKKANwEMAbAVwgC4osBuMqRAVTABMrgTKAApq9IVgCUBPBTgpe7AL4kSoSFACyIACrgIGAGJQIAD0EJeAZyhXgAJxQI0eQqXIBtLFCdRDAXWYMADUcYWl8PHhkdBCcZVUAY0Q7KAALCBoaOGZtPUgMAHIrCGA6MABGQoAfYtLygCZC12IOErLK5nCZEXdySloGZiJ0zOzmQoB3OHsaXkKoJQAaDnJuPgEhewhk+14e5IQrOBoIADpstGFt3d4zjKy4SRXyJWe2+rAGroi8YT7yGIhsQoGg4HBeAAjEBCKYzOYLZarTgIHj8QTMG4zfaRKCHY6nC5wK5YvZnMEQ6EQd6vd5KdhAA)

I get this error `Type '{ hello: string; }' is not assignable to type 'V'. 'V' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to '{ hello: string; }'.(2322)` when trying this.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not possible because `<V>() => Config<V>` is not assigning any real types to `Config`, hence the generic parameter `K` in `type Config<K>` is arbitrary and cannot hold any value.

To help TypeScript determine the type of `K`, you will need to tell it what it can be during run time by adding more generics to `MyType`. I have noticed that the only property that tends to vary in the objects of your example is the key name, hence you can denote which setup should have which key name as follows:

```
const hello: MyType<{'setup1' : 'hello', 'setup2' : 'goodbye' }> = {
```

This can then be parsed by the types as follows:

```
type Config<K extends string> = {
  value: { [F in K]: string };
  onUpdate: (value: { [F in K]: string }) => void;
}

type MyType<F extends { [key: string]: string }> = {
  [K in keyof F]: () => Config<F[K]>;
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strictPropertyInitialization=false#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwGYEsDmAeA0lCAPYCBAEwGcpTgAnFBNAPigF4oBvAKCigDcBDAGwCuEAFxsoAbQBiUWlCwBdMZRp0oAXwDcnKIgCqYYr0JiAFHyGjx02QnlKK1Wmg0BKZo25wUxbevbsoJBQALIgACrgEBgy%20IQk5KySANYQIMpOdA4qzhqMLBxcEjhyqSBwSFBSDqbuTIzwyOgxxQr0fgEAxoiUUAAWEPz8cGJhkZAYrADkpBDAgmAAjFNQYlMDQ3BTADRQM3MLAEwra2hwcMQARiAQK%20r5bDqz80tmdYymhVw8AsJiSRthmsAO5wKj8Yh3bY6Lj6QzGKxUCDdKjEDxQboIUhwfgQAB0wzQpiRKOIeMBcFc0K46ipTwOYEOb3RnxhP0s-ygZwu1ysU1B4MhGmp3zhRhMUBJYLR9QxPRx%20MJxOR0rx3KuNzpNLpWnYQA).

Comment: You will be able to mitigate passing the massive generic type with a helper function to infer it for you, though.

Comment: Sorry could you elaborate on what you mean?